# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 after php update?

Tags: php, http-status-code-500

thank you in advance for your help.

I am encountering an issue, and I'm unsure of the specific reason behind it. I have a page designed to display data after entering a given phrase.

Recently, I added another website built in PHP to the same hosting. Subsequently, I had to update the PHP version on the hosting platform (strato). I'm not certain if this update is the root cause, but even after reverting to the previous PHP version, the issue persists.

When I access the home page, it displays properly. However, upon entering data, I do not receive the expected response. Instead, I encounter the following errors in the console:

In F12 console i have:

POST example.com/api/src/index.php/search 500 (Internal Server Error)

I haven't made any changes to the website code itself; it used to work flawlessly.

Additionally, I attempted to update angularjs to the latest version and replaced it in the FTP.

Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go check the PHP error log (and if PHP error logging isn't enabled, please enable it, then test the code again, then check the log). A 500 status code tells you the server-side code crashed, but it doesn't tell you _why_ it crashed. Hence you need the error log. We can't really help you until you've got a specific error message and a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask].

Comment: `I attempted to update angularjs to the latest version`...noble, but irrelevant. Since a 500 indicates a server-side error, updating the client-side framework is extremely unlikely to help resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This error (code 500) will not help you finding out what's the real problem without having more details.

I would suggest you either take a look at the PHP error_log file, where more details should be reported or, if you would like to see the errors on screen, you could add these two lines on top of the according PHP file

```php
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // ...
```

This will show the errors in the browser / HTTP response. I would not recommend keep this in production environments, because these settings may lead to leaking information to potential attackers.